# libacsccid1_1.1.0-1~trusty1_armhf.deb or similar version for Ubuntu trusty 14.04

Tags: driver, ubuntu, version-control

I have an NFC reader ACR1251U-A1, and I'm trying to install the driver for my NFC reader.

In the folder that I have downloaded from the provider's website, there are only libacsccid1_1.1.0-1~trusty 1_i386.deb and libacsccid1_1.1.0-1~trusty1_amd64.deb versions are existed.

And I couldn't find this exact version on the internet.

Do you know how can I find this package, or do you know whether I can use another package which will be suitable with Ubuntu trusty 14.04?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If the manufacturer only distributes binary drivers for x86(-64) then you are out of luck.  Either they have an ARM driver for linux or they don't -- evidently they do not.

Manufacturers often do not release source code for drivers, meaning somebody would need to reverse engineer this.